# jQuery validation numeric fields on iphone device

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-validate

I have an input with class `numeric` and I use jquery validation to make sure only numeric chars can be typed into this input field. It works all good on desktop and android device, but on iphone+safari, I found it accept more chars than numbers including `(`, `)`, `@`, `$`, `&`, `#`, `%`, `^` and `!`. Does anyone know how to prevent these chars on iphone+safari?

The issue is found on both IOS 4 and 6

Comment: Using this link, it seems that the validator doesn't allow those values: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number  Is this what you're using?

Comment: Yes. The desktop version works well. the problem only found in IOS devices including iphone and ipod